# for loop processing faster than multi-threading

Tags: julia

i have a series of code that i need to run with different values, and as i was testing the speed i noticed that a simple for loop runs faster than a @threads for, below are the functions:

**The simple for loop**

```
input = [0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08]
output = zeros(UInt32,2)
iteratorValue = [0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00]

function loop()
    for i = 0:typemax(UInt16)
        iteratorValue[1] = UInt8((i >> 56)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[2] = UInt8((i >> 48)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[3] = UInt8((i >> 40)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[4] = UInt8((i >> 32)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[5] = UInt8((i >> 24)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[6] = UInt8((i >> 16)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[7] = UInt8((i >> 8)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[8] = UInt8(i&0xff)
        ValueTeste(input, output, iteratorValue)
    end
end
result = @elapsed loop()
println(result)
```

**My last attempt with multi-threading**

```
function loop2()
    @threads for i = 0:typemax(UInt16)
        local iteratorValue = zeros(UInt8,8)
        chacheSpace = 8
        local output = zeros(UInt32,nthreads()*chacheSpace,2)

        iteratorValue[1] = UInt8((i >> 56)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[2] = UInt8((i >> 48)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[3] = UInt8((i >> 40)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[4] = UInt8((i >> 32)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[5] = UInt8((i >> 24)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[6] = UInt8((i >> 16)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[7] = UInt8((i >> 8)&0xFF)
        iteratorValue[8] = UInt8(i&0xff)
        ValueTeste(input, output, iteratorValue)
    end
end

result2 = @elapsed loop2()

println(result2)
```

The ValueTeste function i a series of other 7 functions that loops and calls back to each other so it is kinda hard to explain. But it is mostly xor's, ands and simple mathematical and logical operations, basically this is a 8 bytes cryptography

What have i tried:

- Declaring the output variable local
- Declaring the output variable as a nthreads array so that each thread has it own space
- using the variable chacheSpace to try and fix false sharing

in the example above, i'm running theses loops up to typemax(UInt16) times, and results were as follow in average:

simple for loop: 3.98s
@threads for: 4.2s

How can I improve  the multi-threading?

Comment: Without knowing what `ValueTeste` is or does, it is difficult to know how to help. Also, the first example does not define `iteratorValue`, so the examples are incomplete. Can you write a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you?

Comment: @PaSTE thank you for your time, i edited the first code with the declarations, but sadly, i cannot give you a reproducible example as this a series of functions related to criptography, so i dont think i can come up with an example.

Comment: as @PaSTE said, it's hard to tell what's really going on without knowing what your custom function does, but I suspect given the relatively short wall-time this is a case of your problem not being "hard" enough to be worth parallelizing. Basically it seems to me that there is not much actual computation to do, so any speed-up you get by spreading out the computation is immediately cancelled out by the communication cost.

Comment: Both your functions are highly suboptimal and will be difficult to benchmark properly. Both functions use global variables, which is bad for performance, but particularly bad for multithreading. And `loop2` allocates enormous amounts of temporary memory, which kills performance. It's also not clear if they perform observable work, which means that the compiler can arbitrarily decide to skip some of the work. The benchmarks are therfore not reliable.

Comment: You are measuring compilation times rather than runtimes and these are longer for multi-threaded code as it is more work to compile a multi-threaded code than a single-threaded one. So after you apply other comments us BenchmarkTools.jl to measure the code